# Code executing twice issue in mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Given code is ADD or Edit functionality code
i try to add data but data add two time in database
i am facing issue in save time db.SaveChanges() call two time so data save duplicate in database here is my code

```
                              [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult AddEdit(tbl_uwm_parent model)
            {
    
                if (model.Parent_Id != 0)
                {
                    
    
                        tbl_uwm_parent data = (from c in db.tbl_uwm_parent
                                                        where c.Parent_Id == model.Parent_Id
                                                        select c).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (data != null)
                        {
                            data.Parent_Name = model.Parent_Name;
                            data.Parent_Email = model.Parent_Email;
                            data.Parent_PhoneNo = model.Parent_PhoneNo;
                            data.Parent_Address = model.Parent_Address;
                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
    
                        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                  
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
    
                            model.STATUS = "A";
                            model.UPDATED_DATE_TIME = DateTime.UtcNow;
                            db.tbl_uwm_parent.Add(model);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                        
    
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
    
                        throw;
                    }
                   
                }
                    return Json("Error");
            }
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like? I had this problem and it turned out that I was actually submitting the form twice.

Comment: i checked but issue is code executing two time

Comment: Can you post the HTML for your view?

Comment: A question: you are adding the model to your `tbl_uwm_parent` table if it doesn't have a parent ID already.  But there's no `return` statement after it. You will wind up returning `Json("Error")`, even if the save was successful.